# How do I open my code file with sublime text without it opening my previous files on other tabs

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2

Whenever I open sublime text with my .py files , it opens up all the files on which I am working on opened in other tabs.It's kindof distracting , any way I can open only one file at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for that. Set this in your settings file:

```
"hot_exit": false,
"remember_open_files": false
```